# Oppo Device have Scrolling Issue with WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

On Other devices, There is no such issue but on Oppo Devices When Webview is scrolled sometimes it lags & sometimes it scrolls in the reverse direction. I am not able to figure out the problem Please Find Below My Sample Code, Any help is appreciated in Advance.

Here is Device Configuration
[image]

Here is WebViewActivity

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binder: ActivityWebviewBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binder =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_webview)
    setupView()
}

private fun setupView() {
    with(binder.webView.settings) {
        databaseEnabled = true
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        domStorageEnabled = true
        builtInZoomControls = true
        useWideViewPort = true
        cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
    }
    binder.webView.webViewClient = BrowserClient()
    binder.webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    binder.webView.loadUrl("webview_url")
    //binder.webView.setInitialScale(1)
}

private class BrowserClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)

    }

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (binder.webView.canGoBack()) {
        binder.webView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Which model? What's its android version?

Comment: Device : Oppo A31,
Android Version: 9

Comment: Look! your code is ok. So maybe that phone has a problem

Comment: Issue is persisting only in oppo and vivo devices

Comment: Maybe this version of android on that devices has a bug.